# EF Migrations and context in another dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, migration

I've installed EF 5.0 in my web mvc application, but context is stored in another dll (repository). hen I'm trying to enable migrations I've got error `No context type was found in the assembly 'PI.Web'`. When I try to run command `Enable-Migrations -StartUpProjectName 'PI.Web' -ProjectName 'PI.Data'` I've got error `The EntityFramework package is not installed on project 'PI.Data'.`. PI.Web is my startup project and PI.Data is dll where context is kept. Do I really have to install ef in PI.Data to use Migrations?

Comment: How do you have a context in a class with no reference to EF? The project wouldn't compile. The short answer is yes, to use migrations on a context, the project needs a reference to EF.

Comment: I've got reference, project compile, data are saved and get from db, but when I try to enable migrations I've got errors I'd written in post

Comment: So you're contradicting yourself. In the question you say `The EntityFramework package is not installed on project PI.Data`. In the comment you say `I've got reference`. So is there a reference in 'PI.Data` or not? If not, then there is no way your context is stored in `PI.Data`.

Comment: Your question solved my issue. Exactly the command I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note the connection string must include the full name of the context

YourProject.Whatever.YourContext

Answer (score 0):

how do you create context in Pi. Data if yu ou dóbr reference EF? 
you should reference EF in Data project not Web. Why repository pattern if you still reference EF i n Web project?